# Casting between real floating and integer

Tags: c

While referring to the C99 standard **6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**, I found the following explanation about the possible undefined behaviors while cast between float to integer types.

> If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined

I have the following questions regarding the same. Which of the following conditions classify to an undefined behaviour

1. Signedness of integral part and the integer type are different.
2. The integral part is greater than the MAX value that can be represented by the integer type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are converting to a signed integer type with range [TYPE_MIN, TYPE_MAX], then if the floating-point source value does not lie in the open interval (TYPE_MIN-1, TYPE_MAX+1), the behavior is undefined.

If you are converting to an unsigned integer type with range [0, UTYPE_MAX], then if the floating-point source value does not lie in the open interval (-1, UTYPE_MAX+1), the behavior is undefined.

So yes, both of your conditions produce undefined behavior (so long as you consider the integral part of `-0.5` to not have negative signedness).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! Appreciate your help.